# Anyway to pass a generic type in a constructor to a parent class constructor?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

Is there anyway to get a generic type in a class constructor in order to pass it to a parent constructor?

Given base class:

```
public class BaseSupport<T>{
   private Class<T> type;
   public BaseSupport(Class<T> type){
      this.type = type;
   }
}
```

Is there anyway to create a subclass to do this?

```
public class Support<T> extends BaseSupport<T> {
    public Support() {
       // is there anyway to know what "T" is here?
       super( T.class );
    }
}
```

And then finally, I would simply be able to create a class like:

```
public class MyClass extends Support<OtherClass>{
   // no need to explicitly define a constructor here since the Support class handles it
}
```

I know Guava has [`TypeToken`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ReflectionExplained) to help with retrieve generic type information, but given that `super()` must be the first method called in a constructor, I can't use it to extract the type information to pass to the parent class.

I suspect that this isn't feasible, but thought I would ask to see if there are any features/tricks that I don't know about in Java 7 since 'T' would be available at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

You could effectively do this.

```
public class MyClass extends Support<OtherClass>{
   // no need to explicitly define a constructor here since the Support class handles it
   public MyClass() {
       super(OtherClass.class);
   }
}
```

And in support, have a constructor that accept a `Class` type and call the `super` keyword as I have done above (eliminating `T.class` all together).

---

Update: Alternatively, you can use Reflection to get `ParameterizedType` on your `BaseSupport` class and not need to provide an argument to your `BaseSupport` public constructor.

**Resource:**

- [Reflecting Generics](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=208860).
- [Related Answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403909/get-generic-type-of-class-at-runtime#answer-15008017).

Comment: The problem is in `Support` class constructor where OP naively uses `T.class`.

Comment: Thanks for identifying this. I have updated the post accordingly.

Comment: The whole point is that I am trying to build it such that I don't need an explicit constructor in `MyClass`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza the whole point of this question is to figure out if there is something I can do in the `Support` class to retrieve what `T` is to pass to the parent constructor.  Obviously `T.class` is just a placeholder and does not compile.

Comment: @EricB. That's impossible.

Comment: I realize that BaseSupport, in theory, could be redesigned differently.  But BaseSupport is part of a lib to which I don't have access to modify.  So I was trying to see if there was away around the issue by creating my own "base" class.

Comment: Then, the simplest choice, without worry about reflection, is the one I mentioned, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

Did you see the option mentioned in the `TypeToken` docs?

> Capture a generic type with a (usually anonymous) subclass and resolve it against a context class that knows what the type parameters are. For example:
>
> ```
>    abstract class IKnowMyType<T> {
>      TypeToken<T> type = new TypeToken<T>(getClass()) {};
>    }
>    new IKnowMyType<String>() {}.type => String
> ```

Comment: I did see that and tried to use it, but I couldn't figure out how to use it in my `Support` class and have the type available in the constructor such that I can pass it to the parent class constructor, given that `super()` has to be the first thing called in my constructor.

Comment: super(new TypeToken<T>(getClass())) ?

Comment: Tried those types of combinations already, but they don't work.